# AttributeError: type object has no attribute "id" PYTHON

Tags: python

So I was trying to make a basic python pong game when this error came up:
It seems to say that AttributeError: type object has no attribute "id" which I have no idea what it means.

```
C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/****/untitled/src/testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/****/untitled/src/testing.py", line 113, in <module>
    ball.draw()
  File "C:/Users/****/untitled/src/testing.py", line 36, in draw
    if self.hit_paddle2(pos) == True:
  File "C:/Users/****/untitled/src/testing.py", line 53, in hit_paddle2
    paddle2_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle2.id)
AttributeError: type object 'Paddle2' has no attribute 'id'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the code I used:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, paddle2, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.paddle2 = paddle2
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if self.hit_paddle2(pos) == True:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def hit_paddle2(self, pos):
        paddle2_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle2.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle2_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle2_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle2_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle2_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False


class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

class Paddle2:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 10, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-W>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-A>', self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, Paddle2, 'red')
paddle2 = Paddle2(canvas, 'blue')
while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
        paddle2.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: `Paddle2` _class_ does not have `id`. `Paddle2` _instances_, on the other hand, has. You Ball class wants `Paddle` and `Paddle2` instances, `paddle` is passed correctly, and `paddle2` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass instances of `Paddle` and `Paddle2` to `Ball` constructor.

```
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
paddle2 = Paddle2(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, paddle2, 'red')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, Paddle2, 'red')
paddle2 = Paddle2(canvas, 'blue')
```

should you pass in the paddle2 instance? like this?

```
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
paddle2 = Paddle2(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, paddle2, 'red')
```